# How to crawl other hash in other hash loop

Tags: ruby, loops, hash

I have 2 hash in my Ruby code.

I wanna get data of "d" hash in "c" loop.

```
c = {"2"=>"20", "3"=>"30"}
d = {"2"=>"Du", "3"=>"Bist"}

c.each_with_index do |me,index|
    puts me
end
```

output is:

**2 20 3 30**

I wanna get this output instead:

**Du Bist**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do as below :

```
c = {"2"=>"20", "3"=>"30"}
d = {"2"=>"Du", "3"=>"Bist"}

c.each_with_index do |(k,v),i|
    puts "#{d[k]} at index #{i}"
end
# >> Du at index 0
# >> Bist at index 1

# I don't know why you want each_with_index, instead of each here
# But here is how you can do.
c.each_with_index do |(k,v),i|
    puts d[k]
end
# >> Du
# >> Bist
```

`c` and `d` are `Hash`.`c.each_with_index do |me,index|` here, with each itration `me` first has the value as `["2","20"]`, then `["3","30"]`. Thus `puts me` printing it as `2 20 3 30`. You need to have a look at [`Hash#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D).